# handle location header in apache reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy

I am using Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) and configured it as reverse proxy server for internal web server. My reverse proxy server address is 10.0.0.1 which is exposed to public and my internal server address is 192.168.1.15 which is a private server. The virtual host configuration file is like below.

```
ServerName      web.example.com
ServerAlias     web.example.com
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.15/web/public/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.15/web/public/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
<Location "/">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/web-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/web-access.log combined
```

Expected result: http://web.example.com and Actual result: http://web.example.com/web/public/

When I curl the URL.. $curl -v http://web.example.com

```
Trying 10.0.0.1...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to web.example.com (10.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: web.example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: /
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 30 Aug 2020 13:28:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Location: http://web.example.com/web/public/
Content-Length: 522
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Try removing /web/public/ from your "ProxyPass" and "ProxyPassReverse

Comment: But I want to map "http://192.168.1.15/web/public/" with "web.example.com". If "/web/public/" will be removed, then i have to use "web.example.com//web/public/" to get the result.